# Can I pass a config file directly to tmuxinator on the command-line?

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I'm new to tmuxinator, so forgive me if this is a naive question.

I have a tmuxinator config file (say, `my_config.yaml`,) stored in a source tree of a shared project.

For others to use it, AFAICT they first have to make a soft-link from the config file to inside thier home directory, then launch tmuxinator separately:

```
$ ln -rs my_config.yaml ~/.tmuxinator/
$ tmuxinator my_config
```

This is inconvenient, and also requires that all your config files have unique filenames, lest they collide in `~/.tmuxinator/`.

I'd much rather just be able to do something like:

```
$ tmuxinator my_config.yaml
```

Is there a way to pass the config file to tmuxinator on the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass the config file to tmuxinator on the command line?

Not currently. Feel free to open a feature request/issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues).

Tmuxinator *does*, however, support project level config files. If you move my_config.yml to /project/root/.tmuxinator, you can then start it (from the project root) via `tmuxinator start .` or `tmuxinator local`.

UPDATE:

As I added below in the comments, this is now possible using the `-p` flag:

`tmuxinator start -p /path/to/my_config.yml`

Comment: Good to know; thanks. I've filed a feature request: https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/595

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this in the future: as of v0.11.0, tmuxinator now supports OP's desired use case and a project config file can be passed to tmuxinator via: `tmuxinator start -p /path/to/my_config.yml`

Comment: @pdoherty926 please add this to your answer: tmuxinator start <project name> -p /path/to/my_config.yml

Comment: There is a typo in Rubber Duck's comment: there is no need to add `<project name>` when using the `-p` flag.